# Does JS prototype have access to the argument(s) passed to an object during initialization?

Tags: javascript, arguments, prototype

Everything is in the the title really... I know that functions created using prototype can't have access to private object data/functions, but what about having access to the arguments that were passed to the object when it was created ?

```
var Voice = function (word)
{
   /* 
      I know I can obviously do something like : 'this.word = word;'
      But I was wondering whether there is a standard way of calling an   
      argument from within a prototype function without having to do  
      the above ?
   */
};

Voice.prototype.speak = function ()
{
    console.log({{word}});
};

x = new Voice('all I can say is this');
x.speak();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The functions on the prototype weren't defined within the function that the variables are in scope for, so they don't have access to them.

You can store the variable as an object property and then read it back from there.

```
this.word = word;
```

Comment: oops.. I was updating my post while you were posting your answer.. :-) Fair enough.. this answers my question, thanks!

Comment: It would be cool though, if they had allowed something like `Voice.prototype.speak = function () { this.arguments.word }`, where `arguments` would obviously be a `reserved` word in that context, right ? Anyway.. thanks once again.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this:

```js
var Voice = function (word) {
    this.init_word = word;
};

Voice.prototype.speak = function (){
    console.log(this.init_word);
};

x = new Voice('all I can say is this');
x.speak();
```